# How to avoid mutating the state of the object inside a stream?

Tags: java, object, java-stream, immutability

I have code like people.stream.filter(Object::notNull).map(person -> person.updateAge(...))

I would like to avoid calling updateAge() and even remove that method and make me object immutable. How can I achieve that while keeping the stream structure of the code?

Comment: You could replace `updateAge()` with an accessor method `getAge()` that does not change the person's state. Note that you can do more with accessor methods than just return fields. The representation of a person could include a birth date; the accessor method `getAge()` could compute the current age from the birth date and current time.

Comment: Lets say I want to change the age. Lets say in people collection there are people whose birthday is today.

Comment: So do you want to change it or not? You can't modify immutable objects, obviously.

Comment: I dont want to modify that object directly but rather create a new object will all same fields with age field changed. Is that possible

Comment: @user10994556 - Yes, you could replace updateAge() with a method that copies the object with a new age -- say, makeCopyWithAge().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate objects then you are misusing `map`! it is `forEach` that is for side effects.

```
people.forEach(person -> person.updateAge(...))
```

But no I still like to be functional and use immutable objects. In that case you need to make `updateAge` takes a new age and return a new person object with that very new age.

```
Person updateAge(int incrementBy) {
   ... new Person(..., newAge); 
}
```

And then get a stream of new people like this

```
people.stream.filter(Object::notNull).map(person -> person.updateAge(...))
```

Comment: Then in your second situation `updateAge` is a misleading name, probably `withAge` or `ofAge` would be better

Comment: Thats true @Jack

Comment: Then, you could also use `people.replaceAll(p -> p.withAge(…))` if `people` is a mutable list.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to modify that object directly but rather create a new object will all same fields with age field changed. Is that possible

Yes it is possible. You can override method `clone()` from Object:

```
@Override
public Person clone() {
    try {
        return (Person) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to implement `Cloneable`:

```
public class Person implements Cloneable {
    ...
```

Assuming you have `updateAge()` method like this:

```
public Person updateAge(int age) {
    this.setAge(age);
    return this;
}
```

Then stream chain will looks like:

```
List<Person> newPeople = people.stream()
            .map(Person::clone)
            .map(person -> person.updateAge(...))
            .collect(toList());
```